# FB Messanger bot - can not make sending messages work

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, bots

I am making a FB messenger bot. I can not get the part with making the bot sending a message back to work.

I am using Heroku for the Webhook.

I am following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=__SWFhHocDI

Here is my code (I changed the token variable, I do use the real token):

```
file_put_contents('fb.txt', file_get_contents('php://input'));

$fb = file_get_contents('fb.txt');

$fb = json_decode($fb);

$rid = $fb->entry[0]->messaging[0]->sender->id;

$token = "MYTOKEN";

$data = array(
        'recipient' => array('id'=>"$rid"),
        'message' => array('text'=>"Nice to meet you!")
);

$options = array(
          'http' => array(
                    'method' => 'POST',
                    'content' => json_encode($data),
                    'header' => "Content-Type: application/json\n"
          )
);

$context = stream_context_create($options);

file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/me/subscribed_apps?access_token=$token", false, $context);
```

Can you find any problems? :-) Thank you for taking time.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should try something like this -

```
file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=$token", false, $context);
```